# Codeigniter: How to increase active records in the for loop?

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a table which includes week numbers of the year in its columns. I try to update by increasing these columns' values in nested loops.

I have the following query which attempts to increase the related field of a record.

```
foreach ( $updateVotes as $key => $value ) {

     for ( $week = 1; $week < 53 ; $week++) {

       $increaseValue = $value['week_'.$week];
       $this->db->set("week_".$week , "week_".$week. " +".$increaseValue, "FALSE");

     }

       $this->db->where('id', $id)
                ->update('votes');
 }
```

To achieve my aim, I need output like the one below:

```
UPDATE "votes" 
SET week_1 = week_1 +20,
    week_2 = week_2 +50,
     ...
WHERE id = 1
```

However, when I run the query, it produces the following SQL:

```
UPDATE "votes" 
SET "week_1" = 'week_1 +20',
    "week_2" = 'week_2 +50',
     ...
WHERE id = 1
```

As it also produces single quotes, it throws errors like this: 
   `column 'week_1 +20' cannot found`

How can I escape these single quotes and run the query successfully?

Comment: Did you try to replace `"FALSE"` with `FALSE`?

Comment: I really can't believe it was such a simple mistake. Thank you! You saved my day!

Comment: :D Can I post an answer?

Comment: Yes, please. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official document [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html), you should pass `FALSE` (Bool) instead of `"FALSE"` (String) like this

`$this->db->set("week_".$week , "week_".$week. " +".$increaseValue, FALSE);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Remove Double quotes from **"FALSE"** into **FALSE**